# break-before, break-after, and break-inside do nothing

Tags: html, css, printing

I'm trying to keep an element from getting cut in half when I print the page, but for some reason the CSS properties `break-before`, `break-inside`, and `break-after` do absolutely nothing. I've tried every combination of them I can think of on several elements on the page. Is there some kind of gotcha with these properties? One answer said I can't have `float` elements (which I'm not using anyway), so I added this to my global styles:

```
@media print {
  * {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

I also tried defining a CSS class specifically for forcing page breaks:

```
.page-breaker {
  @media print {
    display: block;
    break-before: always;
    page-break-before: always;
  }
}
```

But this element also has no effect.

Why is this happening? Why are these properties so difficult to use?

EDIT: I'm testing in Chrome Chrome 79.0.3945.88 on OSX 10.14.6.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @epascarello I should have mentioned the browser I'm testing in (Chrome 79.0.3945.88). That table is quite confusing. It shows 4 of the possible values, but above it there are 14 values described. I'm unable to decipher what the support for `page-break: avoid` is because it's not in the table.